# NSTableView & NSNotificationCenter strange behavior

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nstableview, nsnotificationcenter

I got very strange behavior when reloading NSTableView data inside notification observer.

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate
{
    var data: String[] = []

    @IBOutlet var filesTableView: NSTableView!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "droppedFiles:", name: DroppedFilesNotification.notificationName, object: nil)
    }

    func droppedFiles(notification: NSNotification!)
    {
        data += ["123"]
        println(data.count)

        filesTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView!) -> Int
    {
        return data.count
    }

    @IBAction func crazyTest(AnyObject)
    {
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(DroppedFilesNotification.notificationName, object: self, userInfo: [DroppedFilesNotification.fileNamesParameterName: ["123"]])
    }
}
```

First call of crazyTest function displays:

```
1
```

Seconds call of crazyTest function displays:

```
2
3
4
```

Third call of crazyTest function displays numbers 5-13.

If we would remove filesTableView.reloadData() from droppedFiles function then all works fine except table view isn't updated. Any idea why this happens and how to reload table view there?

**EDIT:**

Also, there is no issue in case calling droppedFiles function directly instead of using NSNotificationCenter. But I'd prefer to use notification center in my application.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a view-based table view which (perhaps implicitly) loads its views from NIBs, then its `awakeFromNib` method will get called each time the NIB is loaded. From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH14-SW10):

> **Note:** Calling `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` causes `awakeFromNib` to be
>   called multiple times in your app. This is because
>   `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` loads a NIB with the passed-in owner,
>   and the owner also receives an `awakeFromNib` call, even though it’s
>   already awake.

In your case, you're registering for the notification each time. So, you're registering for it many times over and you receive the notification once for each time you registered.

Comment: Thanks, Ken! I don't know how missed that note ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing the observer. My guess is that you are going into that view controller multiple times and therefore it is registered for the same notification multiple times. Therefore, when the notifications is triggered, the callback gets called multiple times.